# How to make it possible to use colored emoji fonts in Jasper?

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports

I'm working on report in Jasper Studio. It must contain colored emoji.

How to make it possible to work with colored emoji in Jasper?

I know how to add fonts in JasperStudio. I've never had any problems with regular black and white fonts.

I tried to import Noto Color Emoji .ttf (from https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji). But it doesn't work - I can enter an emoji into a text element, but nothing is displayed.

I also tried other fonts, in particular - Segoe UI Emoji font. It's a little better - the icons are displayed, but they are black and white.

Answer (score 0):

Support for Opentype color features like CBDT, COLRv0 and 1 is still spotty especially for native app environments.

Afaik the version provided on [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji) is also based on COLRv1.

However, there is a [github repository](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/fonts) containing multiple versions like the **CBDT** version which might work better.

**CBDT** is a colored bitmap approach that is used by many android emoji font versions.

See also ["Color fonts! WTF?"](https://www.colorfonts.wtf)